# Azure Virtual machine is stuck at "starting"

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm testing Azure using my MSDN account.
All went well, until I went over my spending limit, after which my services were suspended.

After my account was re-enabled, I wanted to start my Virtual Machines again.
However they keep having status 'Starting'.

The user-interface of the Azure management portal seems to offer no methods to remedy this situation.

Any ideas on how to reset these servers, or find a way to determine what is keeping them from finishing the starting process?

Comment: I went through the trial and it expired before I switched to the pay as you go service.  When I got a hold of MS to switch my service, they let me know that all my `VM`'s would need to be recreated.  All the storage was intact, but I had to rebuild the `VM`'s either fresh, or based on the images that were created as disks in storage.

Answer (score 2):

do not delete it, you can use azure powershell to stop it and start it again.  the keep disks lost one of vhd's when we tried to do it that way.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it restart VM using Azure Powershell as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issues and don't know the cause, but you temporarily fix it by deleting the Virtual Machine - you will get the option to delete or keep the associated disks - KEEP THEM.

After about 10-15 minutes, the disks will appear in the My Disks part of the Create Virtual Machine gallery - allowing you to re-create the machine with the same disks. You can also reuse the same name etc.